# Ajax, long-polling, multi users, chat arrived

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

lets have a "complex" site, there are three modules: "links", "home", "chat". Links, home just a static-like page, no need long polling, it doesnt even start. But in case "chat" any time a new message may arrive from other users, and I want to immediatly show it, without refreshing the site.

So, in "chat" a long-polling was started, and it detects that a new chat message arrived, so poll-requests finishes and sends a "send the chatbox-div" message - so that site may refresh the DIV.

But lets imagine three users are watching this module right now. How to notice all of them to refresh the content?

EDIT: how I imagine: lets somewhere save a flag which indicates that the message arrived, and the long polling request is watching this flag. If it changes, get the message, and zero that flag - but then its possible some users (some requests) wont notice that

Comment: With long polling, the client checks the server **periodically** *using AJAX* for fresh content and once received, the new content is simply appended to the div. No need to refresh the page

Comment: I edited the question, to make it more clear

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want the long polling to automatically update the div with the new content? It seems more efficient. But yeah, you can create a flag if you want. It's all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Senario :
One Server;
N Clients in the same Chanel

The server implements a Pool for one chanel;
Pool is configured as follow (it can be an array/class/...) :
**ID**(Integer/string) 
=> A new record is inserted if a client made a connection and it will be identified by his ID
=> This record will be deleted, if the client do deconnection or exit from this chanel
**MESSAGES**(String) : New Messages must be concatenated to the old that are already stored on the pool

Each Time that a client send a new message to the server
1 - All MESSAGES of the pool will be updated by concatenation unread messages by the new one (except for the sender)

Each Time that the client make a request to the server (using Ajax Long Pooling) 
1 - the server will deliver him the right MESSAGE basing on his ID
2 - Erase MESSAGE

With this implementation, client can receive an empty message, so on front-end you have to do the appropriate operation